# Harmonic frequencies of electric guitar are detuned. What could be the cause?

Tags: acoustics

I have tried to record some music with my electric guitar and while playing around and looking the frequencies of single strings I noticed something strange. I took the spectra of the A string and I expected multiples of 440 Hz, but the Results were of by 6 Hz. I recorded again with a tuning fork and I got the 440 Hz as expected.
I used an electric tuning device to tune my guitar and it should have been perfectly tuned. What does this result mean? Is my tuning device broken or is there something I am missing?

[image: A String]
[image: Tuning Fork]

Here is the raw data from the 434 Hz peak:
Frequency[Hz]    Dezibel[db]
...
430,664063  -80,541397
431,336975  -77,470108
432,009888  -70,965828
432,682800  -62,022697
433,355713  -51,955708
434,028625  -38,634003
434,701538  -32,274822
435,374451  -34,905651
436,047363  -48,552521
436,720276  -55,133629
437,393188  -59,501816
438,066101  -72,979942
438,739014  -74,478226
439,411926  -83,606758
440,084839  -86,944931
440,757751  -85,912453
441,430664  -81,394493
442,103577  -93,493988
442,776489  -81,689384
443,449402  -83,698189
444,122314  -95,337143
444,795227  -106,526367
...

Comment: Perhaps your electronic tuning device is improperly calibrated.  If you pluck the A string and hit the tuning fork can you hear beats around 6 Hz?  I don't understand the subharmonics, so something else may be going on ...

Comment: Yeah, I'm confused too. You claim the dominant frequency should be 440 Hz (or maybe 434 Hz), but from the first graph it looks like your subharmonics are louder than your supposed dominant frequency by a good 20 decibels or so. So you should barely be able to hear the note you're supposedly playing, and it shouldn't even sound like the same note as the tuning fork. Are you sure the data was recorded correctly?

Comment: @ garyp: HA! Who would have guessed I would need to calibrate the stupid thing?! You were right, thanks! This is the device: http://images.thomann.de/pics/prod/159505.jpg See where it says "ON...CALI"? Apparently whenever one presses the "On" button it also changes the calibration.

Comment: @ DumpsterDoofus: All whole multiples of 440 are the A tune. It doesn't matter to the human ear if you only hear 440 Hz or the multiples too. The brain "adds" them anyway. Old telephones used to filter lower frequencies, which should have resultet in men sounding much higher, but that didn't happen because the brain substitutes the missing frequencies.

Comment: The question is a bit misleading and suggests that the A on a guitar is 440 Hz, which it is not. 440 is a pretty high note. From this graph, it appears that the fundamental frequency is 110Hz (still an A) not 440. There are no subharmonics here.

Comment: @throwaway17434: I think you've got it backwards, look at the plot. Multiples of 440 would be 440, 880, 1320, 1760. Your peaks are located at 434, 325, 217, and 109. You're tuning the a 4th harmonic of 110Hz to a 440 Hz fork, not tuning the 440Hz fundamental to a 440Hz fork.

Comment: Guitar strings are E2=82.41Hz, **A2=110Hz**, D3=146.8Hz, G3=196Hz, B3=246.9Hz, E4=329.6Hz  http://www.seventhstring.com/resources/notefrequencies.html